# padding margin an inline Flowdocument

Tags: c#, flowdocument

I'm searching for an option to apply a margin or/and padding to an inline element as Span in Flowdocument. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a good overview how to handle text in FlowDocument in the following link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970786.aspx

I used TextBlock. As it seems TextBlock is unable have a margin. So be sure to use padding instead.